# Сканирование портов С#

Tags: c#, сокет, сканирование-портов

Питаюсь сканировать порты но к сожалению не могу проверить правильность роботы программы.
Скачал вот эту [программу](http://melfis.ru/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/). Подскажите как проверить работоспособность?
Пользуюсь ІР который видает провайдер. Результат что все порты открыты, если брандмауэром блокирую порт она все равно говорит что он открыт.

Вот сам код

```
public void Scan()
    {
     int StartPort = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
     int EndPort = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);
     int i;

     progressBar1.Maximum = EndPort - StartPort + 1;
     progressBar1.Value = 0;
     listView1.Items.Clear();

     IPAddress IpAddr = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);
     for (i = StartPort; i <= EndPort; i++)
         {
          //Создаем сокет
          IPEndPoint IpEndP = new IPEndPoint(IpAddr, i);
          Socket MySoc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
          //Пробуем подключится к указанному хосту
          IAsyncResult asyncResult = MySoc.BeginConnect(IpEndP,
                           new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), MySoc);

          if (!asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, false))
            {
             MySoc.Close();
             listView1.Items.Add("Порт " + i.ToString());
             listView1.Items[i - StartPort].SubItems.Add("закрыт");
             listView1.Items[i - StartPort].BackColor = Color.Bisque;
             progressBar1.Value += 1;
            }
            else
            {
            MySoc.Close();
            listView1.Items.Add("Порт " + i.ToString());
            listView1.Items[i - StartPort].SubItems.Add("открыт");
            listView1.Items[i - StartPort].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            progressBar1.Value += 1;    
            }
         }

         progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Забирай оттуда: http://www.gotdotnet.ru/files/425/